# PubSub BigQuery subcription duplicate message with different publish_time

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

Recently, we have implemented PubSub BigQuery Subscription and noticed duplicate messages pushed to BigQuery using below configuration.

```
Write metadata : Enabled
Drop unknown fields : Disabled
Subscription expiration : Subscription will never expire.
Acknowledgement deadline : 10 seconds
Subscription message retention duration : 7 days
Retain acknowledged messages : No
Exactly once delivery : Disabled (cannot be enabled)
Message ordering: Disabled
Dead lettering: Disabled
Retry policy : Retry immediately
```

This was expected behaviour due to [https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery](https://stackoverflow.com) but we have found one single message with 2 different publish_time in landing table and with the same data (JSON).
Didn't find much from the logs and appreciate any leads on the issue.

| message_id | publish_time |
| --- | --- |
| 7376235078582047 | 2023-04-08 12:15:08.664000 UTC |
| 7376235078582047 | 2023-04-08 12:15:12.593000 UTC |

Any leads for further investigation and solution if anyone had faced similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the publish times are different, then the cause was duplication that happened within the Pub/Sub service itself when the message was published. There are retries done for transient errors that may result in a message with the same ID, but different publish times. If you need to distinguish between messages due to any kind of duplication, it is best to include a unique identifier in the message itself or the message attributes.